# How are the hashes in /etc/shadow generated?

Tags: hash, shadow

I was reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_(file)) on the shadow file and it mentioned the format of the lines is like this:

```
$id$salt$hashed
```

So, my question is, how does it work?

I tried to calcualte the hash for my own account to which I had the password so I used this command:

sha512sum
{salt}+{my_clear_text_password}

But the output is different from the hash I see for myself. So how does it work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things to think about (you'll have to read the sources in the Linux coreutils and glibc2 to confirm)

- The output of sha512sum appears to be printable hex notation whereas the output stored in the shadow file appears to be base64 so they will be different.
- I think that the sha512sum in the shadow file has been passed through the hash function more than once ( `#define ROUNDS_DEFAULT 5000` ) whereas the sha512sum just passes the 'file' through the hash once.
- There may be padding added by one or both commands to align the data it may be different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the hash in the same way that the `/etc/shadow` file stores it, use the following command:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512 --salt=YOUR_SALT PASSWORD
```

Comment: The output of this command contains chars not present in the output of `sha512sum`. Is there some more encoding going on for the hash output stored in /etc/shadow?

Answer (score 1):

From the [`shadow(5)` man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow):

> **encrypted password**
>
> Refer to **crypt**(3) for details on how this string is interpreted.
>
> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of **crypt**(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).
>
> This field may be empty, in which case no passwords are required to authenticate as the specified login name. However, some applications which read the /etc/shadow file may decide not to permit any access at all if the password field is empty.
>
> A password field which starts with a exclamation mark means that the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line represent the password field before the password was locked.

From the [`crypt(3)` man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt):

> crypt() is the password encryption function.  It is based on the Data Encryption Standard algorithm with variations intended (among other things) to discourage use of hardware implementations of akey search.
>
> key is a user's typed password.
>
> salt is a two-character string chosen from the set [a–zA–Z0–9./].  This string is used to perturb the algorithm in one of 4096 different ways.
>
> By taking the lowest 7 bits of each of the first eight characters of the key, a 56-bit key is obtained. This 56-bit key is used to encrypt repeatedly a constant string (usually a string consisting of all zeros). The returned value points to the encrypted password, a series of 13 printable ASCII characters (the first two characters represent the salt itself). The return value points to static data whose content is overwritten by each call.

Comment: Seems like a sane answer to me. No idea why it was voted down...

Comment: It's talking about `crypt` encoded passwords. `SHA-512` is very different.

Comment: It should be noted that the glibc2 version of crypt() supports different algorithms (MD5, SHA-256, SHA-512, and, on some systems, Blowfish) depending on the salt value. See the "Notes" section of the man page for crypt(3).